# How to connect to SQL Server in Win7 virtual machine from Mac host?

Tags: sql-server, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I restored a MSSQL backup to SQL Server Express in a Windows 7 virtual machine under Virtualbox. I am attempting to connect to this SQL Server instance from the host (Mac OS) using a user inside the imported database that has credentials to connect. The virtual machine is configured to use a Host-Only adapter. SQL Server express is running inside the VM at WIN7VM/SQLEXPRESS, port 1433.

I am able to connect to Apache in the VM on port 8080 from the Mac host without a problem. I can also telnet into the SQL server at port 1433 from the Mac host, using the host-only IP address (192.168.56.101).

What I am unable to do is connect to SQL server from Navicat in MacOS, or remotely using PHP. Here is what I have tried:

- Disabled Windows Firewall
- Configured SQL server port setting to use 1433
- Enabled SQL server authentication
- Enabled TCP/IP in SQL Server
- Enabled remote connections to SQL server

I am trying to connect with this info:

- Host/IP address: 192.168.56.101 OR 192.168.56.101\SQLEXPRESS (have tried both)
- Port: 1433
- Database: MyDatabase
- Authentication type: Basic
- Username: username
- Password: password

What am I missing here to be able to remotely connect without any issues? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I believe you need to use a Bridged Adapter - rather than a Host-Only adapter. A Host-Only adapter does not use the physical NIC - so that is probably the issue here.

Comment: @Donal: any other ideas? I added a bounty to this question so I would be happy to give it to you if you can help me solve it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out to not be a Virtualbox issue, but a SQL Server authentication issue.

The user I was trying to connect with had access to a database, but did not have a corresponding SQL Server Login.

[MSDN - Managing Logins, Users, and Schemas How-to Topics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337552(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: Finally did it work with Host-Only adapter or a bridged adapter? I feel Host-Only adapter should work too if there is no need to connect to the internet from Windows guest.

Answer (score 4):

I believe you need to use a Bridged Adapter - rather than a Host-Only adapter. A Host-Only adapter does not use the physical NIC - so that is probably the issue here. I have encountered the same issue before.
Using a Bridged Network connection on both the Host and the Guest - will mean that both are on the same network. Assuming the firewall are not blocking port 1433, you should be able to connect without issue.

Comment: I have Adapter 1 set to NAT, and Adapter 2 set to Host-only, vboxnet0. When I choose Bridged Adapter with en0: Ethernet for Adapter 2, then run `ipconfig` from inside the VM, I can't connect from the Mac host to either IP address it returns.

Comment: Are you using AirPort on your host?

Comment: I'm connected via Ethernet on the host, so I set the Bridged Adapter to the Ethernet.

Comment: Setting my adapter to bridge worked for me. I was able to see the server on the same network. Now to just get the right ODBC drivers installed...