# Connect R to SQL Server database in windows virtual machine

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, rstudio

Question: is it possible to connect R Studio on Ubuntu to a SQL Server database that is being used on a virtual machine (Microsoft Windows 10) through the local network?

I will keep looking, I want to make sure it is possible before I spend any more time at this. Thanks.

Update: I couldn't do it. I ended up using Rstudio on the VM alongside Windows 10 through DSN I created. I couldn't bridge Rstudio outside the VM into the SQL server database on the local host. I tried everthing on this SO post [How to connect to SQL Server in Win7 virtual machine from Mac host?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26149305/how-to-connect-to-sql-server-in-win7-virtual-machine-from-mac-host) but no joy.

Comment: It must be possible - they are in the same network after all.

Comment: what kind of Virtual Machine? VMware, VirtualBox, ...? -- Maybe there is an answer on the smaller StackExchange sites.

Comment: @knb it was Oracle VM virtualBox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have access to any virtual machines anymore (I did when I was at a previous job), but this is how you would connect R to SQL Server.

```
toSQL = data.frame(...);
write.table(toSQL,"C:\\export\\filename.txt",quote=FALSE,sep=",",row.names=FALSE,col.names=FALSE,append=FALSE);
    sqlQuery(channel,"BULK
                INSERT Yada.dbo.yada
                FROM '\\\\<server-that-you-can-see>\\export\\filename.txt'
                WITH
                (
                FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
                ROWTERMINATOR = '\\n'
                )");
```

Since insert INTO is limited to 1000 rows, you can dbBulkCopy from rsqlserver package.

dbBulkCopy is a DBI extension that interfaces the Microsoft SQL Server popular command-line utility named bcp to quickly bulk copying large files into table. For example:

```
url = "Server=localhost;Database=TEST_RSQLSERVER;Trusted_Connection=True;"
conn <- dbConnect('SqlServer',url=url)
## I assume the table already exist
dbBulkCopy(conn,name='T_BULKCOPY',value=df,overwrite=TRUE)
dbDisconnect(conn)
```

And, finally . . .

```
library(dplyr)
library(RODBC)

dbhandle <- odbcDriverConnect('driver={SQL Server};server=Server_Name;database=DB_Name;trusted_connection=true')

NEEDDATE <- as.Date('8/20/2017',format='%m/%d/%Y')

# DataSet1
DataSet1<-paste("DECLARE @NEEDDATE nvarchar(25)
SET @NEEDDATE = '2017-07-20'

SELECT      . . .

        )")


DataSet1 <- sqlQuery(dbhandle, DataSet1)
DataSet2 <- sqlQuery(dbhandle, DataSet2)

Combined <- rbind(DataSet1, DataSet2)
```